# Trying to create a word search puzzle and it's not highlighting the words once clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a word search puzzle, but I am encountering some issues that for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out. I'm just starting out with JS so be gentle, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, here is the fiddle with all the files: https://jsfiddle.net/jruiztt/3xgL7wzh/

As far as I can tell, here are the issues:

**Puzzle Squares Coloring Issue:**

Puzzle squares containing letters from the defined keywords are not changing their background color to red and text color to white when clicked.

**Solve Puzzle Button Coloring Issue:**

When the "Solve Puzzle" button is clicked, the background color and text color of the keywords in the puzzle are not changing to red and white, respectively.

**Checkmark Legend Issue:**

The legend checkboxes for keywords are not getting checked off when all the letters corresponding to a keyword are clicked in the puzzle.

**Game Completion Check Issue:**

The "Claim Prize" button is not being enabled even after all the checkboxes in the legend are checked, and all keywords in the puzzle are marked as completed.

**JavaScript Error:**

An error occurs in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: words is not defined" when attempting to solve the puzzle.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const words = ["happy", "birthday", "to", "you"];
  const directions = ["horizontal", "vertical", "diagonal"];

  // Generate a random word search puzzle
  const puzzle = generatePuzzle(words, directions);

  // Render the puzzle on the page
  renderPuzzle(puzzle);

  // Add event listeners to squares for clicking
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  squares.forEach(square => {
    square.addEventListener('click', () => {
      checkWord(square);
    });
  });

  // Add event listener to the "Solve Puzzle" button
  const solveButton = document.getElementById('solveButton');
  solveButton.addEventListener('click', solvePuzzle);

  // Add event listener to the "Claim Prize" button
  const claimPrizeButton = document.getElementById('claimPrizeButton');
  claimPrizeButton.addEventListener('click', claimPrize);
});

function generatePuzzle(words, directions) {
  const gridSize = 10;
  const puzzle = Array.from({
    length: gridSize
  }, () => Array(gridSize).fill(''));

  // Place words in the puzzle
  words.forEach(word => {
    let placed = false;
    while (!placed) {
      const direction = directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
      const row = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
      const col = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);

      placed = placeWordInGrid(word.toUpperCase(), puzzle, row, col, direction);
    }
  });

  // Fill empty squares with random letters
  puzzle.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((cell, colIndex) => {
      if (cell === '') {
        const randomLetter = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
        puzzle[rowIndex][colIndex] = randomLetter;
      }
    });
  });

  return puzzle;
}

function placeWordInGrid(word, puzzle, startRow, startCol, direction) {
  const wordLength = word.length;
  const gridSize = puzzle.length;

  let endRow, endCol;

  switch (direction) {
    case 'horizontal':
      endRow = startRow;
      endCol = startCol + wordLength - 1;
      break;
    case 'vertical':
      endRow = startRow + wordLength - 1;
      endCol = startCol;
      break;
    case 'diagonal':
      endRow = startRow + wordLength - 1;
      endCol = startCol + wordLength - 1;
      break;
  }

  if (endRow >= gridSize || endCol >= gridSize) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    if (puzzle[startRow][startCol] !== '' && puzzle[startRow][startCol] !== word[i]) {
      return false;
    }

    puzzle[startRow][startCol] = word[i];

    switch (direction) {
      case 'horizontal':
        startCol++;
        break;
      case 'vertical':
        startRow++;
        break;
      case 'diagonal':
        startRow++;
        startCol++;
        break;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function renderPuzzle(puzzle) {
  const container = document.getElementById('wordSearchContainer');
  container.innerHTML = '';

  puzzle.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((letter, colIndex) => {
      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.className = 'square';
      square.textContent = letter;
      square.dataset.row = rowIndex;
      square.dataset.col = colIndex;
      container.appendChild(square);
    });
  });
}

function checkWord(square) {
  const wordList = document.getElementById('wordList');
  const words = Array.from(wordList.getElementsByTagName('li'));

  words.forEach(word => {
    const letters = word.textContent.split('');

    if (letters.includes(square.textContent.toUpperCase())) {
      square.classList.add('selected');
      const selectedSquares = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
      const wordFound = letters.every(letter =>
        Array.from(selectedSquares).some(selectedSquare => selectedSquare.textContent === letter)
      );

      if (wordFound) {
        word.classList.add('completed');
        selectedSquares.forEach(selectedSquare => {
          selectedSquare.classList.remove('selected');
          selectedSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          selectedSquare.style.color = 'white';
        });
        checkGameCompletion();
      }
    }
  });
}

function solvePuzzle() {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  const wordList = document.getElementById('wordList');
  const words = Array.from(wordList.getElementsByTagName('li'));

  words.forEach(word => word.classList.add('completed'));

  squares.forEach(square => {
    const isKeywordSquare = words.some(word =>
      Array.from(word.textContent).some(letter => letter === square.textContent.toUpperCase())
    );

    if (isKeywordSquare) {
      square.classList.add('selected');
      square.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      square.style.color = 'white';
    }
  });

  checkGameCompletion();
}

function checkGameCompletion() {
  const wordList = document.getElementById('wordList');
  const completedWords = Array.from(wordList.getElementsByClassName('completed'));

  const claimPrizeButton = document.getElementById('claimPrizeButton');
  claimPrizeButton.disabled = completedWords.length !== words.length ? true : false;
}

function claimPrize() {
  alert("Congratulations! You've successfully solved the puzzle!");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#wordSearchContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  user-select: none;
}

.square.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#legend {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#wordList {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}

li.completed::before {
  background-color: #333;
}

#buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test-style.css">
  <title>Word Search Puzzle</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wordSearchContainer"></div>
  <div id="legend">
    <h2>Words to find</h2>
    <ul id="wordList">
      <li id="happy">happy</li>
      <li id="birthday">birthday</li>
      <li id="to">to</li>
      <li id="you">you</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="solveButton">Solve Puzzle</button>
    <button id="claimPrizeButton" disabled>Claim Prize</button>
  </div>
  <script src="test-script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The error occurs in `checkGameCompletion()` - you refer to `words` but it doesn't exist in that function.

Comment: In your `const isKeywordSquare =` line, you are testing the letters of the keywords - which are lowercase - against the content of the squares, which you force to uppercase. Hence, none match so it never hits the `isKeywordSquare` block.

Comment: When you fix the uncaught error it should fix the Claim button issue - that's what's preventing it.

Comment: You have the same lowercase / uppercase problem in `checkWord()`.

Comment: which ide are you using ?  is it not highlighting / linting correctly ?

Comment: Thanks @NickGris, the uncaught error is fixed. I am still having issues with the isKeywordSquare. I want it all to be uppercase. I don't want any lower case letters

Comment: @JeromeRuiz: Either make your words uppercase on the page, or simply use `toLowerCase()` on `square.textContext` instead of `toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

The words array is defined in your DOMContentLoaded event listener function. The const declaration is block-scoped it isn't available in your `checkGameCompletion()` function.

You should pass the words array the same way you did with the `generatePuzzle(words, directions)` function.

Answer (score 0):

**Puzzle Squares Coloring Issue:** The condition `letters.includes(square.textContent.toUpperCase())` is not fulfilled and nothing happens after. You should convert square letter to lowercase one to find it in letters from the word, so `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Thanks all for your input, everything seems to be working now. I jsut have one more issue.  I only want to select letters that are part of one of the keywords, problem is that it selects the letter, even if no matter what direction you choose, does not end up in completing one of the keywords. E.g "Happy" is one of the keywords, however there are other ''H" in the puzzle. I only want the H that is part of the word happy to be selected. I hope what I said makes sense.